# Yesterday's date in where clase with HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql, datetime, parameters, oracle11g, where-clause

In my query I currently have user enter datetime.

**Current query**

```
where TableT.STARTDATETIME  >= To_Date('?DATE1?','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
          and TableT.STARTDATETIME <= To_Date('?DATE2?','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

***User would enter***
for Date1: `10-02-2013 00:00:00` 
for Date2: `10-02-2013 23:59:59`

*Parameter* :- `?DATE`? & `DATE2` is just a parameter for user to enter dates.

**Need** 
How can I made sql automatically enter yesterday's date starting from `00:00:00` to `23:59:59`?

I know I can use use something like `sysdate-1` but not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
TRUNC(TableT.STARTDATETIME) = TRUNC(sysdate-1)
```

for this purpose to truncate both dates to the day on both side of the check. However, for this to be efficient, you'd need a function index on `TRUNC(TableT.STARTDATETIME)`.

Maybe better in general from a performance aspect:

```
TableT.STARTDATETIME >= trunc(sysdate-1) AND TableT.STARTDATETIME < trunc(sysdate);
```

This includes yesterday 00:00:00 (the `>=` ), but excludes today 00:00:00 (the `<`).

**Warning!** Keep in mind, that for **`TIMESTAMP`** columns - while tempting because of its simplicity - **don't** use `23:59:59` as end time, as the 1 second time slot between `23:59:59` and `00:00:00` might contain data too - and this gap will leave them out of processing...

Comment: If it's a `DATE` column then the precision means there isn't any data between `23:59:59` and `00:00:00`. Valid point for a `TIMESTAMP` column though.

Comment: @AlexPoole right - I subconsciously assumed that it is a TIMESTAMP... Corrected

Answer (score 4):

It would be:

```
where TableT.STARTDATETIME >= trunc(sysdate-1) and
      TableT.STARTDATETIME <  trunc(sysdate)
```

Avoid truncating the column value itself -- although you can place an index on Trunc(TableT.STARTDATETIME) you'd need another one to support time-based queries, and it's a fine way to obscure the distribution of values from the optimiser.

Have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208) for more info on date and timestamp arithmetic, and at the [Trunc(datetime, format)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions209.htm#SQLRF06151) function for other useful ways of manipulating dates.